# Productos con categorias relacionadas

Tags: php, mysqli

Estimados tengo un problemita de pronto sea algo sencillo pero no doy con la solución espero uno de Uds. pueda salvarme.

Necesito mostrar productos que tienen categorias padre e hijas y que al dar clic en la categoria padre muestre tambien los productos de sus categorias hijas pero solo me muestra los productos de las categorias hijas, para esto tengo dos tablas una de productos y otra de categorias.
[image: Tablas]

La tabla productos tiene un campo categoria que es el mismo id de la tabla categorias.
la tabla categorias tiene un campo padre que por defecto tiene valor de 0, cuando es una categoria hija tiene el mismo valor del id de la categoria padre, es decir, en la tabla categorias, si la categoría hombre tiene el id 25 la categoria camisetas que tiene el id 42 tiene el padre 25 y en la tabla productos el campo categoria es 42, y yo deseo que me traiga los productos del id 25 y del 42, espero no haber hecho un enredo.

Estoy trabajando con PHP y mysqli, por favor alguien deme una manito. ¡Gracias!

[image: Gráfico del catálogo]

En la venta 1 me mustra las categorias padres.
En la ventana 2 al escoger la categoria ACABADOS me deberia mostrar todos los productos de sus categorias hijas solo he logrado traer el nombre de dichas categorias.
En la ventana 3 deberia mostrar solo los productos de la categoria hija seleccionada en este caso ADITIVOS.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from pam_categorias_catalogo where padre = $categoria and id_negocio = '$negocioid'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
$array[] = $row['padre'] ;
} 
echo $array;

$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from pam_catalogo where estado = '1' and id_negocio = '$negocioid' and categoria = $array")or die(mysqli_error($con));
$numero = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
if($numero == 0)
{
echo "Este negocio no tiene productos ingresados en su catalogo";
}
else
{
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes mostrar tú código?

Comment: $query1 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from pam_categorias_catalogo where padre = $categoria and id_negocio = '$negocioid'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
  $array[] = $row['padre'] ;
  } 
  echo $array;
  
  $query2 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from pam_catalogo where estado = '1' and id_negocio = '$negocioid' and categoria = $array")or die(mysqli_error($con));
  $numero = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
  if($numero == 0)
  {
  echo "Este negocio no tiene productos ingresados en su catalogo";
  }
  else
  {

Comment: Te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y añadir el código ahí.

Comment: ok gracias es que soy nuevo disculpas

Comment: No te preocupes :) . A ver si he entendido bien lo que estas intentando hacer. Tienes unas categorías principales a las que pertenecen otras categorías secundarias y a su vez, a estas categorías secundarias pertenecen determinados productos. ¿Lo que quieres hacer es que al elegir una de las categorías principales aparezcan todas sus categorías secundarias y todos los productos?

Comment: las tablas manda foto de como tienes los ID

Comment: Si Ferni exactamente asi, que al escoger una de las categorias principales me traiga todos los productos de esa categoria y sus categorias secundarias

Comment: Una forma de hacerlo sería hacer un `select`de la primera categoría o conseguir la ID de alguna manera, ya sea desde un formulario, o similar. Con esta ID tendrías que buscar todas las categorías hijas y guardar sus ID, y a continuación hacer un `select` por cada categoría hija para saber sus productos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola veo que ha pasado un año y no recibiste respuesta, 
Lo que se debe hacer en PHP y MySql es leer los productos 1 a 1 con un simple query que te trae todos los productos.
Luego debes hacer una rutina que tiene como entrada 2 parámetros el ID de la categoria Raiz ($rootcate), que es la que buscas y el Id de la categoria del producto ($cate_id) .
Con estos 2 valores haces la rutina de buscar el $cate_id y compararlo el valor obtenido de la categoria padre con $rootcate, si no son iguales debes seguir buscando hasta que la busqueda te de la categoria Raiz y si nunca consigues una igual el producto no clasifica, 
si consigues uno igual haces un retorno de que el producto si clasifica en ese arbol de categorias.